# No BCC recipients in sent emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

my outlook 365 (version 2304 16.0.16327.20200) do not show in sent  items bcc recipients at all, bcc are enabled during mail compose, but when email is sent with "To" and "BCC" only TO recipient is shown in the sent email header. No matter if I even modify the columns and add BCC column it's empty - is any way to figure it out?

Comment: [The field is hidden but it can be found used easily with a simple click.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-hide-and-view-the-bcc-blind-carbon-copy-field-04304e27-63a2-4276-8884-5077fba0e229). Or perhaps I am confused by your question

Comment: so, you misunderstood me, the BCC option is enabled while editing the message, when such a message is sent with the 'TO' recipient and the 'BCC' recipient, then going to the sent messages I click on this message and in the header I see only 'TO' recipient nothing more, you got it?

Comment: Are you opening the email or previewing it in the reading panel. I am very familiar with Outlook.

Comment: no matter if I do one click on particular message from the all send messages and the look at the header, or if I open it in the new window in both cases I see only "To" recipient.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a known bug / expected behaviour in certain scenarios.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/outlook-bcc-field-is-not-displayed-on-some-items-in-the-sent-items-folder-6a907f45-bf1c-d6e5-77dd-f49e79687a50

Specifically if your Outlook is in Online mode, or you're including a large number of recipients in the BCC field.

Aside from using a distribution list (not helpful after the fact obviously), the suggested work around is to open the sent item, use the Other Actions menu and click `Resend This Message`, which will then let you see the list of users currently within the BCC field... then just make sure you don't hit Send otherwise they'll get a second copy.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question on this.

1. Desktop Outlook connects to an Exchange Server (Microsoft365) in the cache mode profile.
2. It also connects to another mail server using IMAP/SMTP.

In case of the IMAP mail server, is this BCC not displaying because of the large number of BCC recipients used as one of the two possibilities in that support document?

FWIW, the old desktop Outlook (perpetual license so I think the desktop Outlook included in Office 2016) running on Win8.1, it has no problem showing BCC recipients of a sent message sync'd with the Sent folder of the IMAP mail server.